# How can i select rows for specific cells from same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table with tenants and their addresses.

A tenant can have several addresses and at each address can appear several times (closed, open, modified).
The tenant appears first with an address (**first**) after which he can have several changes on the first address (**closed, open, modified**) or he can have other addresses (**closed, open, modified**).

How can I extract the date of closing the first address.

The problem come with a twist. The name of streets are not exactly like first addres. It can contain St., Ave. in their names.

The table look like this:

| id | Tenant | code | Street | Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | First | Abbey | 5 | 01.01.2021 |
| 2 | Alice | Modify | Abbey Ro. | 5 | 02.01.2021 |
| 3 | Alice | Open | Elm St | 3 | 02.01.2021 |
| 4 | Alice | Close | St. Abbey | 5 | 05.01.2021 |
| 5 | Bob | First | Fifth | 10 | 01.02.2021 |
| 6 | Bob | Open | Fifth Ave | 222 | 01.02.2021 |
| 7 | Bob | Close | Fifth Ave | 222 | 05.02.2021 |
| 8 | Bob | Close | Ave Fifth | 10 | 06.02.2021 |

The expected result should by like this:

| id | Tenant | CloseID | Street | Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 4 | Abbey | 5 | 05.01.2021 |
| 2 | Bob | 8 | Fifth | 10 | 06.02.2021 |

I have a feel the answer is there but i can't grab it :)
Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Is the ID column really a column in the table? How did Bob get ID 2?

Comment: the street change from the 5th to the 8th? you need somtihing euqual in both records

Comment: Is result table with own id's. In fact is just an enumeration (generated numbers or criteria number). Is not necessarily to be there :)

Comment: I don't get it.  Why doesn't row 4 close the address on row 3?

Comment: Is completely other address. I wished to exemplify that a tenant can have multiple homes and multiple operations on them. In this case Alice have 2 homes : Elm Street 3 and Abbey Aley 5. First was Abbey 5, then.modefied Abey 5. After that opened Elm 3 and closed Abbey 5. Need to know when she/he closed first Home, in this cas Abbey 5

Answer (score 1):

you need sometihng equal in both records (first and close)
for exemple, if you are sure that 'Number' it's every time the same, and the id user it's unique you can use it

```
SELECT * FROM tenant WHERE Number = 10 AND Id = 5 AND code = "close"
```

but this it's only an example, you can use it with your tenant, beacuse you can easily run into bug
for example if the tenant have more than 1 address with the same Number

if you know where the other word (st. , ave etc )  are in the Street, you can use %

example

7 | Bob | Close | Fifth Ave | 222 | 05.02.2021

sql:

```
SELECT * FROM tenant WHERE Number = 10 AND Street LIKE 'Fifth%' AND code = "close"
```

8 | Bob | Close | Ave Fifth | 10 | 06.02.2021

sql:

```
SELECT * FROM tenant WHERE Number = 10 AND Street LIKE '%Fifth' AND code = "close"
```

otherwise you have to change the table
for example by adding the Address No. field
indicating if the address is the first, second, third etc .. for that person

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I must run this select for every tenant, comparing his FIRST address (street and number) with HIS same address (street and number) but with CLOSE code.

Comment: you're welcome  - If i'd help you please mark this answer as correct and close this topic.

Comment: The table have ~10000 records with many tenants :)

Comment: if the addresses are not the same I think it is impossible,
you should add a sequential "Address id" field and make sure that the users "id" too
so as to create a while loop where every time you add +1 to both ids, to consider all users and compare the id of the first address with the closed address

Comment: Tenant can have multiple address but one address remain the same (name and number) Except the suffix name (that "ave", "st" from beginning or end off the street name). What is change is just the code (open, close, etc.) and the date. From multiple address of a tenant only one address have the "First" code in it.

Comment: Address aka Home

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```sql
with cte as(
select tenant, code, street, number, date, row_number() over (partition by tenant order by date desc) as rank
from tenants
order by date desc
)
select * from cte where rank = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. The street names is not the exactly the same. I must use something like "'%StreetName%'"

Comment: For paragraphs i use two returns.

Comment: It's not quite what I intended. The results is base on date which is not always correct. But is extracting something, which is way better than what i obtained so far. I must compare every tenant FIRST address (street and number) with HIS same address (street and number) but with CLOSE code. Thanks.

Comment: I agree I did misunderstand your problem :)